# Floating point errors in C++

Tags: c++, floating-point

I need to have some float divisions that must be accurate like double version of them. I can change divided value - it represents a mapping and I can offset it - to correct eventual floating point errors.

To correct the errors, I use following code:

```
do 
{
    float fValue = float(x) / 1024.f;
    double oldFValue = fValue;
    double dValue = double(x) / 1024.0;
    if(oldFValue != dValue)
    {
        x += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}while(1);
```

With this code, for

```
x = 11
```

I have in debugger (Visual Studio 2010):

```
fValue = 0.010742188
oldFValue = 0.010742187500000000
```

Can you please explain why double value is different from float value? Is this a debugger problem or a floating point conversion problem? I'm asking this because:

```
if(oldFValue != dValue)
```

is never true, even though it should be. Should I compare the float value with the double value in some other way? I need the result of float division to be exactly same as the double division.

Comment: With fixed decimal digit precision, `1/3 * 3` won't be equal to `1` (it'll be .9999999). That's just how limited precision arithmetic works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to read (and understand) [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 2):

How much do you know about [single precision float](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision)?

It's stored as `<sign><exponent><mantis>`. You can write the final number as:

```
(sign ? 1 : -1) * 0.1<mantis> * 2^(expontent - 127)
```

As you can see number is ALWAYS stored as number `>1` and as a binary fraction. Unfortunately some numbers such as `0.1 dec` are periodic in binary so you won't get exact result with float.

You may try using this: `if(oldFValue != (float)dValue)` and if it won't work you can also try:

```
if(oldFValue*32 != (float)dValue*32)
```

This will cause:

```
mantis >> 5
expontent += 5
```

Which may eliminate your error (try 1 (weird, but may work in some cases), 2, 4, 8, 16..., 2^n).

*EDIT*: Definitively read [Johnsywebs link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 2):

11 / 1024 is exactly representable in both `float` and `double`. So of course `oldFValue == dValue`.

Comment: But why my debugger is showing different values?
fValue = 0.010742188
oldFValue = 0.010742187500000000

Comment: @Felics Apparently it's rounding float to 8 significant places and displaying double with higher resolution. Enter `(doube)fValue` in the watch window and you wil see the exact value.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with floating point is that there are **infinite number of rational numbers** at any non singleton range. However, you only got **finite number of bits to represent** your floating point number.

Thus - **floating points numbers are not real/rational numbers** - and behave differently. You should expect it to be not exactly as a real number would have behaved.

For this reason you should never check equality of floating points using `operator==`. you should calculate the `delta=abs(num1-num2)`, and check if it is smaller then some value you can tolerate its error.

As @Johnsyweb said, reading and understanding the attached article is important to handle floating points correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Most of floating point operations are performed with data loss in mantissa, even when components are fit well in it (numbers like 0.5 or 0.25). 
For example

```
a + b + c
```

is not the same as

```
a + c + b
```

Order of mul operation components also matters.

In order to fix issue necessary to know how fp numbers are represented by machines.

Perhaps this will help:
http://stepan.dyatkovskiy.com/2018/04/machine-fp-partial-invariance-issue.html

Below is the C example of a + b + c issue. Good luck!

*example.c*

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Helpers declaration, for implementation scroll down
float getAllOnes(unsigned bits);
unsigned getMantissaBits();

int main() {

  // Determine mantissa size in bits
  unsigned mantissaBits = getMantissaBits();

  // Considering mantissa has only 3 bits, we would then get:
  // a = 0b10   m=1,  e=1
  // b = 0b110  m=11, e=1
  // c = 0b1000 m=1,  e=3
  // a + b = 0b1000, m=100, e=1
  // a + c = 0b1010, truncated to 0b1000, m=100, e=1
  // a + b + c result: 0b1000 + 0b1000 = 0b10000, m=100, e=2
  // a + c + b result: 0b1000 + 0b110 = 0b1110, m=111, e=1

  float a = 2,
        b = getAllOnes(mantissaBits) - 1,
        c = b + 1;

  float ab = a + b;
  float ac = a + c;

  float abc = a + b + c;
  float acb = a + c + b;

  printf("\n"
         "FP partial invariance issue demo:\n"
         "\n"
         "Mantissa size = %i bits\n"
         "\n"
         "a = %.1f\n"
         "b = %.1f\n"
         "c = %.1f\n"
         "(a+b) result: %.1f\n"
         "(a+c) result: %.1f\n"
         "(a + b + c) result: %.1f\n"
         "(a + c + b) result: %.1f\n"
         "---------------------------------\n"
         "diff(a + b + c, a + c + b) = %.1f\n\n",
         mantissaBits,
         a, b, c,
         ab, ac,
         abc, acb,
         abc - acb);

  return 1;
}

// Helpers

float getAllOnes(unsigned bits) {
    return (unsigned)((1 << bits) - 1);
}

unsigned getMantissaBits() {

    unsigned sz = 1;
    unsigned unbeleivableHugeSize = 1024;
    float allOnes = 1;

    for (;sz != unbeleivableHugeSize &&
          allOnes + 1 != allOnes;
          allOnes = getAllOnes(++sz)
          ) {}

    return sz-1;
}
```